# How to mute audio on arch linux?

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux

I had this working with the following command up until I upgraded my video card from an Nvidia 780 to the 1080.

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle
```

I have these commands for raising and lowering the volume that also stopped working but I was able to fix them:

```
amixer sset Master 2%+ unmute
amixer sset Master 2%- unmute
```

I was able to fix the volume commands by editing my `/etc/asound.conf` file:

```
defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.ctl.card 0
```

The value was 1 I changed it to 0.  I figured this out with `aplay -l` which says that my nvidia display adapter seems to have some sort of sound module:

```
$ aplay -l 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

However, that does not affect the mute command, it still does not work.  When I run it I get the following error:

```
$ amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle
ALSA lib control.c:1375:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL pulse
amixer: Mixer attach pulse error: No such file or directory
```

Google searches suggest something with `pulse` but I've yet to find a configuration that fixes it.  Any ideas?  I suspect there is another place that I need to update the adapter from 1 to 0...but I don't remember where I might have set that :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this to successfully toggle mute (on PulseAudio):

```
 pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle
```

Comment: +1 Works indeed, but still eager to know, why that error happens